# Render D3 svg from function to ExtJS panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, d3.js, extjs4, extjs4.2

I'm new to ExtJS and D3, and trying to render some svg from a function to a panel.

```
callthisfunc = function(contentPanelId) {

            d3.text("data.csv", function(datasetText) {
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);

            var sampleSVG = d3.select('productContentPanelId')
            .data(parsedCSV)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100);

            sampleSVG.append("circle")
            .style("stroke", "gray")
            .style("fill", "blue")
            .attr("r", 40)
            .attr("cx", 50)
            .attr("cy", 50)
            });
    };
```

This code is supposed to draw a circle for each row in data.csv to the panel **productContentPanelId**.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            id: 'app-viewport',
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: '2 2 2 2' 
            },
            items: [{
            id: 'app-header',
                xtype: 'container',
                region: 'north',
                height: 50,
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [{
                    id: 'HeaderPanelId',
                    xtype: 'box',
                    flex: 0.8,
                    border: false,
                    html: "MyTitle"
                }
                ]
            },{
                id: 'app-portal',
                xtype: 'panel',
                region: 'center',
                layout: 'fit'
            }]

            });

            var containerPanel = Ext.getCmp('app-portal');
            containerPanel.add({
                id: 'productMainContentPanelId',
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    border: false,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        align: 'stretch'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        id: 'whatifProductButtonPanelId',
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        cls: 'transitionPlannerToolbar',
                        flex: 0.1,
                        layout: {
                            type: 'vbox',
                            align: 'stretch'
                        },
                        items:[{
                                xtype: 'button',
                                text: 'Overview',
                                margin: '2 2 0 2',
                                scale: 'large',
                                height: 80,
                                iconCls: 'coverageIcon',
                                iconAlign: 'top',
                                listeners: {
                                    'click' : function(btn, event, eOpts) {
                                            callthisfunc();
                                        **//TRYING TO RENDER THE CIRCLES BY CALLING FROM HERE.**
                                            }
                                        }


                            }]
                        //left bar
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'productContentPanelId',
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        border: false,
                        layout: {
                            type: 'hbox',
                            align: 'stretch'
                        },
                        flex: 0.9,
                        **//WANT TO RENDER THE CIRCLES IN THIS PANEL.**
                    }//center box
                    ]

            }); //add containerPanel

        });//end of onReady
```

The rest of the code works fine, except the rendering. The control goes through the function as well. If I add some console log at the end of the function, it gets logged.

Also, I would like to add the name to the circles. The names are in the first column of data.csv

Comment: Sencha forum question on similar requirement:- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?254956-Integrating-d3js-components-inside-extjs4-viewport

Comment: Check this out:-
https://github.com/jmcdonald69124/ExtjsD3Charts